# Dynamically (user) generated form in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, dynamic

I need to add the following functionality to a Rails project:

**Current functionality:**

A *ProjectUser* hasMany *Projects*
A *Project* hasMany *Users*.
A *User* can signup to a *Project* with basic email/password combo.

**Required functionality:**

A *ProjectUser* can add a *Form* to a *Project*
The *Form* is then presented to a *User* as a second step to signing up.
A *ProjectUser* can choose from a predefined list of form items when they add the form. (For example an Age field, a Company size field, a Country field etc.)

**Gems**

I've been looking at Gems, but everything I've found is stale (Pre-rails 3). So my question is two-fold. Can anyone recommend a stable and current Gem that would offer this functionality, and if not, how should I approach this?

**Without Gem**

My current thinking is that I create a *Form* model that hasMany *FormItems* which a *ProjectUser* can add to their form using a table with checkboxes for each item. In order for this to work the form items need to be polymorphic - they are all form items but are unique in the kind of information they present/gather. (text field, combo, date picker etc). Once a *ProjectUser* has made their decisions and selected the form items they want, I would then render store these decisions on the *Form*.

The part of this I am a little unclear on is the relationship between the *Form* and the *User*. A *ProjectUser* needs to save their decisions regarding which fields to have in the form somewhere. It would make sense to me that there is a *Form* model to store these decisions, so each *Project* has one *Form*, then when a *User* wants to sign up to a project I build a sign-up form based on the data in the *Project*'s *Form* model. The generated form itself though is a form for the *User*, not for the *Form* model, so when the user submits the form they are logged in and their new *User* model is populated using the form data.

Does this make some kind of sense?

Comment: As far as I understood the scenario, I think the Form is related to Project and not the User. Since every project has a separate form, there will be a direct relation between them. On a sidenote, [Formtastic gem](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) looks like a well-maintained repo.

Comment: @Kashyap Thanks, but that's what I suggest - 'each Project has one Form'. I'm already using Formtastic and yes it's excellent. However it is the dynamic layer on top of Formtastic that I'm unsure how to handle.

Comment: Sorry if this is sudden but did you ever find a solution? I tried a manual solution and it's working fine, just not the most elegant solutions I've used. Could you please let me know if you've found anything? Thanks!